# Format datetime object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to format php datetime object to following "May-27-1990" format

Comment: You won't have a PHP datetime object in JavaScript. You'll have a string or something else. You need to provide code showing how you're getting that object to JavaScript. Also show what you've tried.

Comment: Also, do some research. Searching on your title gets me [Format Date time in AngularJS](//stackoverflow.com/q/12920892)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 parser={value => value.replace(new RegEx(curr+"s?|(,*)","g"), '')}
```

new RegEx is taking regular expression in form of string as first parameter so you can add variables there ;)